# Dynamically sized arrays in LLVM-IR by allocating new memory if the size became bigger

Tags: llvm, llvm-c++-api

I’ve been thinking on how I could implement arrays can be implemented, without the size of the array being known at compile-time.
An idea was to check if the size of the object trying to be allocated is bigger than the chunk of memory that has been allocated for that variable every time when an assignment to a variable happens. If so a new allocation happens with the size of the object trying to be allocated and the old chunk is freed. However I cannot know the size of the object that is being assigned at compile-time, so I’d have to check this at run-time. Another problem I have is that I'd have to change the pointer to the AllocaInst, but that wouldn't work because of the SSA form of IR.

Is this even a good way to achieve dynamically sized arrays, or should I do something else, like making a new data structure? If I'm on the right path, how can implement this?Any help is greatly appreciated!
Tom

Comment: LLVM doesn't generally check the bounds (absent `inbounds`), so you can use same type and just index past the end.

Comment: That doesn't sound very memory safe to me... Is there a safer way to do this?

Comment: LLVM IR is basically an assembly language with struct types and a bit of extra baggage hre and there. Assembly languages aren't safe. Compilers and VMs provide the safety-related parts as part of mapping from their higher-level model to LLVM's low-level virtual machine.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But is there a safer way to implement this, as I want my language to be more or less memory safe and not just poke into memory at random. Do I have to manage the memory on my own? If so, how can I know how big the array is at compile time, as I need to allocate the appropriate amount of memory.

Comment: Yes, you have to implement it yourself. I did for "my" language, which is also memory safe. How can you do it? That depends on your language, and in particular on its type system.

Comment: So what you're saying is that LLVM doesn't have a way to simplify this/do the heavy lifting, if I am understanding you correctly. Thanks for the answer!